python place the longest word in list last
list1 : ['beg', 'begs', 'big', 'bug', 'buggies', 'bugs', 'bus', 'egg', 'eggs', 'gig', 'sub', 'sue', 'use'] BUGGIES

I have a list of words but want to put the longest word 'buggies' at the end of the list, but keep the order alphabetically except for the longest word. There might be a case where there are more than one word meet the max(len), in that case it would be nice to have those words at the end. but i'm hoping just to get the first one found.
Currently, I am finding that word and putting it outside of the list like shown, but ideally I'd like that shown like this:
list1 : ['beg', 'begs', 'big', 'bug', 'bugs', 'bus', 'egg', 'eggs', 'gig', 'sub', 'sue', 'use', 'buggies']

Any help on this would be appreciated, I'm just starting to teach myself Python.
What I've tried, well nothing on that but this is what I have currently:
sortedwords = sorted(list, key=len)
possible_words = sorted(list)
print('list1:', possible_words, max(possible_words, key=len).upper())


Sort the list alphabetically.  Find the longest word in the list.  Remove it, then add it back to the list at the end.  What is the difficulty?

see here.

Determine the length of the longest word. Then use a sort function that checks whether the current word has the maximum length or not.
list1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"]
maxlen = len(max(list1, key=len))
list1.sort(key=lambda s: (len(s) == maxlen, s))

The result is ['five', 'four', 'one', 'six', 'two', 'seven', 'three']. "seven" and "three" are the longest words and are placed at the end of the list.
The key function returns a tuple in which the first value is 1 if the length is equal to the maximum length, and 0 otherwise. This is consequently the first sort criterion. The second value is the string itself, so that the words are sorted alphabetically in their respective groups.

Gents (and ladies too) I'm new to this, and I appreciate all the answers, but the one that resonates most with me is L Tyrone, its well commented easy to follow and now I've learned a few things like words.remove and words.append. Not saying that the other answers are not good, but this one is at my level where I can understand. Thank you all for your contribution.

This is a good problem to use a for loop in:
max_word_len = 0
longest_word_index = -1

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if len(list1[i]) > max_word_len:
        max_word_len = len(list1[i])
        longest_word_index = i

temp_long_word = list1[index]
del list1[longest_word_index]
list1.push(temp_long_word)

Of course, this example can be condensed a bit, but since you mentioned you were just starting I gave this so that you could understand what was happening clearly.

bro your solution don't work for more than one word in the list. You need to maintain a list of all max_len indices in the list . and finally delete them all from the list and append them at end

They said they were hoping to just get the first one found. If they need more, its trivial to expand the code to do so.

Along it is not working for full solution it is written in totally unpythonic way.
1st of all -1 in python indexing is meaningfull, so you cannot just assume this index as non existing, it is refering as last item.
Second, you have already max() function, why not to use it to make code more clear, more readable and easy to support? (@Matthias answer contains good example of usage). Ok, consider you want some more logic in your loop and you need element and index itself -> then use enumerate().

Probably could be a bit more pythonic in retrospect, thanks for this comment

Find the max length, then sort by whether words have that length.
m = max(map(len, list1))
list1.sort(key=lambda s: len(s) == m)

Attempt This Online!
